# Eclipse software management

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How to streamline/automate the configuration of Eclipse?

Given N developers running a mixture of Ubuntu and Mac OS X, all with the same version of Eclipse, how to make sure that:

- Each developer, on top of his favourite "Available Software Sites" selection, has a common set of installation sources?
- Each developer has an easy (automated?) way of installing a base set of plug-ins?
- Each developer can just as easily install a custom plugin developed in-house and distributed over the local network?
- No automatically deployed plugins conflict with any others a developer might already be using?

I would post this to serverfault.com if it wasn't that I am more interested in a "scripting" answer than a traditional "system management" solution... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you can use Pulse. It is free. For even more control you go to their paid versions called "freelance team" and "private label"

Check it out at http://www.poweredbypulse.com